# Return null or something nullable from lambda in transformation mehtod WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive, spring-webclient

In a Spring WebFlux chain I use a map operation which sometimes may return null and I get a warning :
`Return null or something nullable from lambda in transformation mehtod`.
I believe when data is null it doesn't actually map input to `null` but it will raise an exception instead.
What is the best way to handle the scenario ?

Map method which is nullable :

```java
public Pojo parseJson(String json) {
    try {
        // parse 
        return pojo;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

My reactive chain :

```java
public Mono<Pojo> query(long id) {

    Integer value = idMapper.getValue(id);

    if (value != null) {
        return repo.query(value)

                        Parse Method
                             |
                             v
                .map(this::parse);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear how the two code snippets are connected. Also, why do you return null from a method returning a Mono? It should return a Mono, not null. Same for parseJson: why do you ignore all the exceptions that happen there, instead of propagating them?

Comment: @JBNizet I edited my question to make it more clear about the connection. Can you give me a sample in the way you are talking about.

Comment: Initialise the return "pojo" variable before hand as null. And initialise the pojo inside the try catch method. If there's an error set pojo = null and return pojo.

Comment: Here's what I mean: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/492c0f796e6dc54e48a3ed1772368267

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When working in a functional/reactive world you should try to avoid all null checks and try to never return null from any methods.

Instead return `Optional<T>` when there is a risk for a null return, and return `Mono.error` when there is an error in a function that returns `Mono`. Or return `Mono.empty` if you just want to skip returning something.

By using optional you can rewrite the code to something much cleaner.

```
public Optional<Pojo> parseJson(String json) {
    // Return an optional if there is risk for a null.
    return Optional.ofNullable(new Pojo());
}

private final IdMapper idMapper = new IdMapper();
private final Repo repo = new Repo();

public Mono<Pojo> query(long id) {

    // By returning an optional from the idMapper 
    // you can chain on and avoid null checks.
    return idMapper.getValue(id).map(integer -> repo.query(integer)
            .map(s -> parseJson(s).map(Mono::just)
                    .orElse(Mono.empty())))
            .orElse(Mono.error(() -> new NotFoundException("No Pojo with ID could be found")));
}

class Pojo {
    // Some pojo class
}

class Repo {
    public Mono<String> query(long id) {
        return Mono.just("Foo");
    }
}

class IdMapper {

    public Optional<Integer> getValue(long id) {
        // Here return an Optional instead of null!
        return Optional.of(1);
    }
}
```

Here i return Optionals and a make some decisions to either return a Mono.empty or a Mono.error depending on what happens.

Comment: If you are using WebFlux for reactive programming, use flatMap instead of map like this: 
`.flatMap(s -> parseJson(s).map(Mono::just).orElse(Mono.empty())))`

Comment: It depends on the usercase. `flatMap` and `map` have different usercases, so you dont ”have to” use flatmap